# Cake PHP joined query returned as associative array

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

OK, here is my table/model structure: Models are associated approprately.

[image: table structure]

I am trying to query the **sum of holding value** for a given client id, with the date for a given sum of value as the array key.

I having consulted the docs I have produced the following parameters for my query in the Client model:

```
$findParameters = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Account.client_id' => $clientId,
        'Holding.holding_date = LAST_DAY(Holding.holding_date)', //gets month-end dates only
        'MONTH(Holding.holding_date)' => array(3,6,9,12) //Use for quarter-end dates
        ),
    'fields' => array(
        'Holding.holding_date',
        'SUM(Holding.value) AS portfolio_value'
        ),
    'group' => array('Holding.holding_date')
);
```

When I run the query by doing

```
$holdings = $this->Account->Holding->find( 'all', $findParameters );
```

I get a result like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Holding] => Array
                (
                    [holding_date] => 2009-12-31
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [portfolio_value] => 273239.07
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Holding] => Array
                (
                    [holding_date] => 2010-03-31
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [portfolio_value] => 276625.28
                )

        )
...
```

Which is great but I want the result in an array like this:

```
Array (
    [2009-12-31] => 273239.07
    [2010-03-31] => 276625.28
    ...
)
```

So I try doing:

```
$holdings = $this->Account->Holding->find( 'list', $findParameters )
```

But I get the error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Account.client_id' in 'where clause'
```

The query looks as if it is no longer performing the joins on the tables. Any idea why, given it works fine if I use `all` instead of `list`? And how to get my desired result?

---

EDIT: I have acheived my result using Cake's `hash` class but was wondering if a direct query is a superior and more efficient method.

My method:

```
    $holdings = $this->Account->Holding->find( 'all', $findParameters );

    $values = Hash::extract($result, '{n}.0.portfolio_value');
    $dates = Hash::extract($result, '{n}.Holding.holding_date');

    $result = array_combine($dates, $values);
    return $result;
```

Comment: ha, just finished my answer with the Hash tip too. Good you found it yourself ;) -edit: actually, I do it in a different way, but `Hash::combine` is doing what you do : 2 extract and one combine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### General comment

CakePHP's ORM is great for easy find queries (including `group by` `sort`...). When it comes to more advanced stuff, you'll need either to process the data retrieved in PHP or make [plain SQL Query](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query).

### About Associative Arrays

[`Model::find('all')`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-all) or [`Model::find('first')`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-first) will always return an associative array. The other find methods will return different kind of arrays, but you won't be able to get the result you're looking for using out-of-the box Model functions.

### About fields not being added to the correct subarray

To get your field properly displayed together when you have `SUM()`, `AVG()` or `COUNT()` you can read here [about `virtual fields` in SQL Queries](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#virtual-fields-in-sql-queries)

### How to extract/format arrays in CakePHP

The easiest way would be to use the [`Hash`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html) class to extract and format the data the way you want.

Using [`Hash::combine`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash%3a%3acombine) you could achieve what you're looking for like this :

```
$result = Hash::combine($holdings, '{n}.Holding.holding_date', '{n}.0.portfolio_value');
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get an SQLSTATE error when I use `AS Holding.portfolio_value`

Comment: Although your method without the first step does work, and a 1-liner is better than a 3-liner!

Comment: @harryg I've added a link to the doc where you can see the proper way to perform what I was trying with the first step.

Comment: Helpful but can't be used on conditions. Your method works well without though and I trust it is quite efficient!

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
$findParameters = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Account.client_id' => $clientId,
        'Holding.holding_date = LAST_DAY(Holding.holding_date)', //gets month-end dates only
        'MONTH(Holding.holding_date)' => array(3,6,9,12) //Use for quarter-end dates
        ),
    'fields' => array(
        'Holding.holding_date',
        'SUM(Holding.value) AS portfolio_value'
        ),
    'group' => array('Holding.holding_date'),
    'contain' => array('Account),
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that makes no difference